# Is there a line-linkable version of RFCs?

Tags: rfc

For example, if I want to reference an example of multipart form data in RFC 2046, the best I can do as far as I can see is to write something like this to the docs:

> Go to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-5.1.1, scroll to page 20, then in the bottom part of the page...

It feels quite wrong. Is there a version of RFCs that is linkable to each line? For example, their repository on GitHub or something.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [*Copyright Policy and Trust Legal Provisions (TLP), Frequently Asked Questions*](https://trustee.ietf.org/docs/Copyright-FAQ-2010-6-22.pdf) :

> Anyone can publish and translate unmodified IETF Documents and Contributions for any purpose, even outside the IETF Standards Process.

So you can create a github repository and upload all RFC's, you then will have a line-linkable version of RFCs.